# Error with doctrine:schema:validate for Payum Token

Tags: symfony, payum

I am setting up Payum as per the docs here: http://payum.org/doc/0.10/PayumBundle/get_it_started

I am using this entity here for my security token:

```
namespace Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Token;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="payum_security_token")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PayumSecurityToken extends Token
{
}
```

When I attempt to setup my database I get this error:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                          
  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\PayumSecurityToken" sub class of "Payum\Core\Model\Token". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Token;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="payum_security_token")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PayumSecurityToken extends Token
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

It creates a table with only one column: id

What am I doing wrong or what can I do to resolve this?

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.2",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "*@stable",
    "payum/paypal-pro-checkout-nvp": "*@stable"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set up the mapping in your config.yml file? (I added auto mapping at the end).

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                payum:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: xml
                    dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping

                    # set this dir instead if you use `payum/payum` library
                    #dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Core/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping

                    prefix: Payum\Core\Model
            auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Ah yes this wasn't exactly the issue, as I did have auto_mapping: true. I believe I was overriding my doctrine.orm values as I had two sections of doctrine: in my config.yml

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction